# Should I edit the jsfiddle after the question has been answered?

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle

So I've been wondering about this:

On the one hand the question is a record of a problem to be solved. On the other hand, people come to stack overflow for the solution, and since the question requires code with a link in SO, the problem is already on record.

So what do you think?

Comment: It is a record for that question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, fork the fiddle instead. The jsfiddle is part of the *question*. If someone asks you a question and you get a satisfactory answer, you don't go back and change the question, right? Same goes here. Original code in the question, improved/correct code in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, people should be able to make out the problem without going to the jsfiddle.

Now, the jsfiddle is a record of the problem, which people will want to be able and reproduce, and the existing jsfiddle is perfect for that.

What you *can* do is create a *new* jsfiddle with the fix and post that - either as an update to the question or in a comment.